# JqueryMobile style issue text box in portrait

Tags: css

I am trying to simply make a page that has a form on it.  i need it on one line to be like textbox "%" space textbox "%"  however when i put the code in it in portrait mode on the iPhone it places it one on top of the other instead of side by side.  i have told it the textboxes they are 55px wide and that is working.  but no matter what i try i can not get them side by side.  this is the code snip that i am using.

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="percentselectingdiv">
    <label for="grp1percent">Percent Selecting:</label>
    <input  type="text" name="grp1percent" id="grp1_percent_select" value=""  />
    <label >%</label> 

    <input type="text" name="grp2percent" id="grp2_percent_select" value="">
    <label >%</label> 
  </div>
```

i am thankful for any help... CSS is not my strong suit...

Answer (score 0):

add `float: left` in your text box's style

```
<input  type="text" name="grp1percent" id="grp1_percent_select" value="" style="width:80%;float:left" />
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/qF925/